# Session parameter is empty ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I am trying to write a "contact us" page, which displays some of the data entered by the user from the login page (contact page requires login). To do that I am using a session variable:
code from login:

```
Session["User"] = account.Email;
Session["Password"] = account.Password;
Session["Name"] = account.Name;
return Redirect("/Contact/contact");
```

Code from Contact controller:

```
public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            // if session user is null (e.i. user has not been logged in) redirects user to login page
            if (Session["User"]==null)
            {
                return Redirect("/Login/login");
            }

            string name = Session["Name"] as string;
            string email = Session["User"] as string;

            Account acc = new Account(name, email);

            return View("contact", acc); // else returns contact html page
        }
```

Here is how info is supposed to be displayed:

```
@model Final_Project.Models.Account
<p><span>Name</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="your_email" value="@Model.Name" /></p>
<p><span>Email Address</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="your_email" value="@Model.Email" /></p>
```

But the text boxes display nothing. Since contact page is displayed, Session variable cannot be null (as in that case if statement would execute from controller, redirecting user back to login page). How can I access "Name" and "Email" strings from Session?

EDIT:
Apparently the problems were with the way I passed values to the model itself. Session variable had nothing to do with my issue

Comment: have you set a breakpoint to see the session variables values?

Comment: Can you post your app startup code?

Comment: `Session["Password"] = account.Password;` that's weird, never do that. You are inviting intruders to hack

Comment: @Rahul its just an example dont worry about safety

Comment: did you debug acc variable has values?

Comment: @asd I checked value of Session, it has some parameters such as Session ID and other boolean parameters, as well as "Results View" where the 3 parameter names "Name" "Email" and "Password" could be seen, but I could not find the values themselves

Comment: @Hien, no acc is null, as well as the string values that I pass to constructor, I am guessing `Session["Name/Email"] as string` returns null.

Comment: If you can not find its value, check when you do the assignment `Session ["Name"] = account.Name;`. Maybe the account object is not retrieving the values.

Comment: @asd I wrote this line `string temp = Session["User"] as string;` in login page right after assigning `Session["User"] = account.Email` and it does contain the correct value (edit: I mean temp string does have account.Email's value stored in it)

Comment: And `account.Email`has the correct value?

Comment: @asd yes, if `account.Email` is "test", `string temp` also becomes "test". But for some reason same does not work on the ContactController

Comment: @asd actually, I just re-checked, `Session["User"]` has correct value in Controller, but `Session["Name"]` is null

Comment: I wouldn't use a Session at all. I'd utilize the MVC framework and pass the values you want with a ViewModel.  You can get the current user with the User, identity obj.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have sessionState configuration on your `web.config`
If so when you get the values of Session already expired.

```
<sessionState mode="inProc" timeout="30" ></sessionState>
```

Try to read from HttpContext

```
var name  = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"];
// the assignment for email is User as you referred?
var email = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["User"];
```

**Edited**

check if you are using any of this and are destroying your session

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
Session.Abandon();
Session.Clear();
```

Comment: @Ach113 any news? have you check if your are destroying the session?

Comment: I was incorrectly passing the values to Session variable from the beginning